# Pull data from server onmousewheel?

Tags: javascript, optimization, setinterval, mousewheel

I have a `POST` request that pulls data from a server, according to parameters that are adjustable by the user through `number inputs`. Simply listening to the `change` event is not enough, because I want the data to refresh while using the mousewheel to change the input value.

Calling my refresh function with something like that is clearly not optimal:

```
$('input').on('mousewheel', function(){
    refresh_data();
});
```

There would be a lot of requests, and because they are asynchronous, I can never know for sure if the last request to be completed will be the last one I send.

What I currently use is a `setInterval` to watch an object containing intervals (rounded timestamps) where a refresh has been requested. Inside the `mousewheel` listener, I add the next interval to the object, **as** a property/key, to avoid duplicates.

Something like that:

```
var i = 100;
var obj = [];

$('input').on('mousewheel', function(){
    // add next interval to obj;
    obj[Math.ceil(Date.now()/i)*i] = true;
});

var check = setInterval(function(){
    // refresh if current interval is in obj
    var t = Math.floor(Date.now()/i)*i;
    if(obj[t]){
        delete obj[t]; // remove from obj
        refresh_data();
    }
}, i);
```

I tested this code, on my machine, with `i=50`, and the object is always empty, which is what we want, but with `i=30`, as soon as I go too fast with the wheel, I see some old intervals accumulating in the object. This is caused by the `setInterval` is skipping beats, so whatever value I choose for `i`, some user with less CPU could "*skip the wrong beat*", and end up finishing his mouse wheel movement seeing a result that does not match the parameters value.

I feel like maybe i'm making this more complicated than it has to be, so i'm asking:

**What would be the best way to pull data from server onmousewheel, considering:**

1: I want to **constantly** refresh the data **as** the user rolls the wheel over an input field.

2: I want to be **100%** sure the presented data **after** the wheel movement is always **accurate**.

Comment: Have you tried the Intersection Observer API? It's a native interface for checking if elements are in view. And I think what are trying to recreate with the `setInterval` is called a *debounce function*. There are multiple examples on the web.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Thanks, this is actually very useful !

Answer (score 1):

Try using the document offsetheight like the below code. This will work when user scrolls down and reaches the end of scroll. The behavior is kind of like a recycler view of android.

```
window.onscroll = function(ev) {
      if ((window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset ) >= 
      document.body.offsetHeight) {
           alert("you're at the bottom of the page");
     }
  };
```

Comment: But better way to do this is use `addEventListener` and event `scroll`

Comment: Beware that if there is no scroll possible this will not actually work